# Delete rows in reverse but skip header row

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to find a way to delete rows in reverse with != in excel sheet using openpyxl but skip header row 1.

The following way deletes the header row and I am not sure how to add the skip row 1:

```
for c in reversed(ws7['M']): 
    if c.value != 'Integration Live': 
        ws7.delete_rows(c.row)
```

I can delete without reverse this way below but have not been able to figure how to reverse it so the index doesn't get messed up during deletion (causing some rows to be missed by deletion process).

```
for row in ws7.iter_rows(min_col=13, max_col=13, min_row=2, max_row=None):
    if row[12].value != 'Integration Live':
        ws7.delete_rows(row[12].row)
```

Any suggestions on how I can delete rows in reverse while skipping the header row?

I have tried this but get an exception:

```
for row in reversed(ws7.iter_rows(min_col=None, max_col=None, min_row=2, max_row=None)):
    if row[12].value != 'Integration Live':
        ws7.delete_rows(row[12].row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ws['M']` returns a tuple the easiest thing is to ignore the first element:

```
cells = ws['M'][1:]
for row in reversed(cells):
    …
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
for c in reversed(ws7['M'][1:]):
    if c.value != 'Integration Live':
        ws7.delete_rows(c.row)
```